# True False Null ComboBox

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, combobox

I'm struggling on the development of a component in WPF.
Here's my issue:

I have a bool? property that I want to bind to the SelectedValue of a ComboBox.
My ComboBox should have 3 options: "Yes" (bool == true), "No" (bool == false), "" (bool == null).

I created a UserControl that inherits from the ComboBox. In the constructor, I populated the ItemCollection with the needed values ("Yes"/"No"/"").

CodeBehind:

```
public class YesNoNullComboBox : RadComboBox
{
    public YesNoNullComboBox()
    {
        this.Items.Add("Yes");
        this.Items.Add("No");
        this.Items.Add(string.Empty);
    }
}
```

XAML:

```
<utils:YesNoNullComboBox SelectedValue="{Binding BoolValue}" />
```

I managed to get something operating the way I want to, but for this, I had to use a Converter. Thus, I have a UserControl AND a Converter to add to my XAML.

I thought about setting my UserControl to use the Converter by default, but I didn't figure out how..
Is this even possible ? Or is there a better way ?

Comment: "UserControl that inherits from the ComboBox" - user controls are intended to *aggregate* another controls instead of inherit them.

Comment: I didnt get exactly what you mean by third para

Comment: I've just edited my question to make it clearer

Comment: Is this what you want : http://www.telerik.com/forums/selectable-null-value-in-radcombobox

Comment: No it's not what I'm looking for, unfortunately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to specify converter in your binding declaration, but you can do this *inside*.
I've sketched this:

1) a helper class to store string values to operate in `ComboBox` and converter:

```
public static class ThreeStateComboBoxItemsSource
{
    public const string None = "(none)";
    public const string Yes = "Yes";
    public const string No = "No";

    public static readonly string[] ItemsSource = new[]
    {
        None,
        Yes,
        No
    };
}
```

2) converter:

```
[ValueConversion(typeof(bool?), typeof(string))]
public sealed class NullableBoolToStringConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value == null)
            return ThreeStateComboBoxItemsSource.None;

        return (bool)value ? ThreeStateComboBoxItemsSource.Yes : ThreeStateComboBoxItemsSource.No;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        switch ((string)value)
        {
            case ThreeStateComboBoxItemsSource.Yes:
                return true;
            case ThreeStateComboBoxItemsSource.No:
                return false;
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }
}
```

3) user control. I don't want user to be able to override the behavior of `CombeBox` (e.g., set another `ItemsSource`), I've wrapped `CB` into `UserControl`, instead of inheritance:

XAML:

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApplication4.ThreeStateComboBox"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication4"
             mc:Ignorable="d">

    <UserControl.Resources>
        <local:NullableBoolToStringConverter x:Key="NullableBoolToStringConverterKey"/>
    </UserControl.Resources>

    <ComboBox x:Name="InnerComboBox"
              SelectedItem="{Binding Value, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}, Converter={StaticResource NullableBoolToStringConverterKey}}"
              ItemsSource="{x:Static local:ThreeStateComboBoxItemsSource.ItemsSource}"/>
</UserControl>
```

Code-behind:

```
public partial class ThreeStateComboBox : UserControl
{
    public ThreeStateComboBox()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public bool? Value
    {
        get { return (bool?)GetValue(ValueProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ValueProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ValueProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "Value",
        typeof(bool?),
        typeof(ThreeStateComboBox),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault));
}
```

4) Usage sample:

```
    <local:ThreeStateComboBox Value="{Binding MyProperty1}"/>
```

Since converter is used inside user control, you don't need to use it elsewhere, just bind `bool`/`bool?` property to `Value`.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for.
Thank you very much Dennis.

Answer (score 3):

The purpose of ValueConverters is to bind 2 properties that have incompatible types. Here you want a boolean to become a string. Implicit cast to string give you "true" or "false", but not the strings you want.

In my view ValueConverters are the best and simplest solution to your situation.

Comment: That was my first guess, and I got it to work this way.
What bothers me, is that my custom UserControl is then implemented in 2 different parts. One is the UserControl, the other one is the Converter. Is there a way I could gather these parts together ?
Thus, I wouldn't have to add the UserControl AND the Converter in the XAML, everytime I want to use it.

Comment: Why not? It just wiil be a dependancy of your usercontrol, nothing to be ashamed of that. Any way, I don't see another clean solution.